# Getting Error uploading zip to Fredhopper due to: 401 Authorization Required

Tags: 2013-sp1, smarttarget, fredhopper, dynamic-publishing, publishingfailed

i am using tridion 2013 sp1 with smarttarget 2014 sp1 and fredhopper 7.5 on windows machine on premise. my CD and fredhopper instance are running on same machine.

i am getting blow error while publishing component.
i have done some changes in deployer confing for smarttarget and jar files.
 using this link

> http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-28D61030-27C1-4F1F-9117-A32E9F8FE16D

error while commiting deployment : failed during post transaction uploading zip to Fredhopper due to: 401 Authorization Required

```
 2016-06-01 18:15:57,162 ERROR HostedEnvironmentDeployer - Error uploading zip to Fredhopper due to: 401 Authorization Required
2016-06-01 18:15:57,163 WARN  CommitPhase - Failure during the post-transaction and the transaction will NOT be rolled-back
2016-06-01 18:15:57,163 WARN  CommitPhase - Failure during the post-transaction and the transaction will NOT be rolled-back
2016-06-01 18:15:57,183 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to execute onSuccess event in phase: Deployment Commit Phase for transaction: tcm:0-14049-66560
2016-06-01 18:15:57,183 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to execute onSuccess event in phase: Deployment Commit Phase for transaction: tcm:0-14049-66560
2016-06-01 18:15:57,183 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-14049-66560
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Error uploading zip to Fredhopper due to: 401 Authorization Required
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.HostedEnvironmentDeployer.uploadFile(HostedEnvironmentDeployer.java:290) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.HostedEnvironmentDeployer.deploy(HostedEnvironmentDeployer.java:39) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.utils.SmartTargetXMLUtils.persistFredhopperXML(SmartTargetXMLUtils.java:189) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperOutputBuilder.persistFredhopperXML(FredhopperOutputBuilder.java:119) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperDeployerModule.process(FredhopperDeployerModule.java:76) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:77) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.onSuccess(CommitPhase.java:116) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runSafeEvent(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:240) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:101) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_75]
```

Comment: Sounds like deployer doesnt have access to place the file at Fredhopper location "C:\fredhopper\<Indexer>\data\fas-xml-incremental\catalog01"! Could you check this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check following things in your smarttarget_conf.xml:

1. Deployer does have access to place the file at Fredhopper location which would be something similar to "C:\fredhopper\Indexer\data\fas-xml-incremental\catalog01" (should be defined at IndexeServer=>Deployment=>Location of your smarttarget_conf.xml on your deployer)
2. The error stack shows that deployer is trying to deploy on hosted environment. If you are not using hosted Fredhopper environment, make sure Hosted=>Enable is set to false.
3. Make sure you have provided correct authentication data for Indexer and qserver

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply it helps me by mistake i have set Hosted=>Enable  to true now after setting it false it works fine.